# Javascript layout not working on mobile, only desktop

Tags: javascript

Im having trouble with my JS-code. I write in VSC, and use Chrome as browser. in the "preview" everything looks as it should, but when I upload the webpage, the JS-functions only show as it should on a desktop, not on cellphones. Why is this?

I got several boxes sorted by date with JS. So the closer the date, the higher up the box comes. And when the date has passed, the box goes away.

I really can´t figure it out. Should´nt it work on all devices if it is functional? How do I fix this issue? Chrome should support JS by now?

-The problem is that the my grid items does not get sorted by date on mobile devices, but on desktop they do, by JS.

// Thanks!

The site:  [www.skjerdetnokke.no](http://www.skjerdetnokke.no)  (work in progress of course, and in Norwegian, but you´ll see what I mean when you open in both desktop and cellphone)

My JS-code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
  var divArray = Array.from(divs);
  divArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    var timeA = new Date(a.getAttribute('data-time'));
    var timeB = new Date(b.getAttribute('data-time'));
    return timeA - timeB;
  });
  divs.forEach(function (div) {
    return div.remove();
  });

  var grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  divArray.forEach(function (div) {
    return grid.appendChild(div);
  });
});

var currentDate = new Date();
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".container")
gridItems.forEach(function (item) {
  var itemDate = new Date(item.getAttribute("data-time"));
  if (currentDate > itemDate) {
    item.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't replicate. I tested on mobile seems to be working. Could you provide an image on what's wrong on mobile?

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on us opening an external website on multiple devices. Your question needs to be self-contained, including a [mcve].

Comment: On my phone the content does not sort by date. But it does on my desktop....

Answer (score 1):

But why are you listening to **DOMContentLoaded** which fires before stylesheets, images, subframes; and I don’t know what else, has loaded?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

});
```

Why are you in such a hurry to operate when you should instead be listening to...

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){

});
```

Comment: Hello PassThru! 

Im not that good in JS. I found a code and tweaked it so I could make it run. 